# wow.js with Angular producing warnings

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component that uses `wow.js`.

I installed `wow.js` with `npm` and connected it through `angular.json`.

I have everything working properly but I am getting two warnings in the console:

`MutationObserver is not supported by your browser.`

`WOW.js cannot detect dom mutations, please call .sync() after loading new content.`

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Since these are warnings, the project doesn't break so it's not critical to fix this, but it would be nice to have these warnings go away.

Here is my compnent.ts file only showing the necessary parts:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WOW } from 'wowjs/dist/wow.min';

export class AboutComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  wow = new WOW();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.wow.init();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`wow = new WOW(  {  live: false});`

from https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/166